# How to CAST/CONVERT a column to integers that has string values in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm stuck on this one.

Basically I'm selecting values from a column of type `VARCHAR`. But when I select these values I need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` them all to integers.

the problem is in the column I'm selecting values from some of the values contain string characters, so when I run the query, I get an Error saying the following:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'NA' to data type int.

And here is my `select` statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  DP.Owner_Faculty_Full_Desc AS 'Faculty'
, DP.Programme_Full_Desc AS 'Programme'
, LEFT(FA.Teaching_Start_Date_Key, 4) AS 'Year' 
, SD.Last_Secondary_School_Name AS 'School'
, CAST(CASE WHEN SD.Last_Secondary_School_Decile_Code = 'UN' THEN '0' ELSE SD.Last_Secondary_School_Decile_Code END AS INT) AS 'Decile'
, COUNT(FA.Student_Demographics_Key) AS 'Total Applicants 2014'
, SUM(SE.Total_EFTS) AS 'Total EFTS'
```

I need all values from `SD.Last_Secondary_School_Code` column to be pulled in as an integer.

Comment: What do you do with non-integer values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just use a `case`:

```
(CASE WHEN SD.Last_Secondary_School_Decile_Code = 'UN' THEN 0
      WHEN SD.Last_Secondary_School_Decile_Code not like '%[^0-9]%'
      THEN CAST(SD.Last_Secondary_School_Decile_Code AS INT)
 END) AS Decile
```

Comment: Perfect! That did exactly what I wanted it to, cheers for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope it is good to know this new (at least for me :) ) syntax:

```
SELECT 
 id, 
 value, 
 IIF(TRY_PARSE(value AS int) IS not NULL, value, 0) AS Result 
FROM 
  table1
```

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126(v=sql.110).aspx